# Symfony: Allow multiple mime-types

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4, symfony-forms

I am trying to allow multiple mime-types to be included in my file upload. I tried something like this :

```
$this->validatorSchema['filename'] = new sfValidatorFile(array(
  'required'        => false, 
  'path'            => sfConfig::get('sf_upload_dir'),
  'mime_categories' => array(
    'application' => array(
      'application/pdf'
    ),
    'web_images'  => array(
      'image/jpeg',
      'image/pjpeg',
      'image/png',
      'image/x-png',
      'image/gif',
    )
  ),
  'mime_types' => array('application', 'web_images')
));
```

I donot want to enable all type of mime-types to be included in my upload and also I donot want to merge the categories/types to a single array. Has any one faced this before or knows why this is happening ?

From `sfValidatorFile.class.php`

```
$mimeTypes = is_array($this->getOption('mime_types')) ? $this->getOption('mime_types') : $this->getMimeTypesFromCategory($this->getOption('mime_types'));
```

It seems to be accepting array and seems like I am doing it right. Am I missing something here ?

Comment: Which mime type do you want to allow?

Comment: pdf's and images for now, my concern was how rather than which I want to enable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sfValidatorFile doc says:

`mime_types: Allowed mime types array or category (available categories: web_images)`

(sfValidatorFile.php, line 27).
It allows mime types array OR (one) category (not categories array). That's why your code isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You mixed lots thing in the wrong place. Keep it simple. You can give a parameter `mime_types` with every mime_types you want.</strike>

For example, here I accept all kind of images or a pdf:

```
$mime_types = array(
    'image/jpeg',
    'image/pjpeg',
    'image/png',
    'image/x-png',
    'image/gif',
    'application/pdf',
);

$this->validatorSchema['filename'] = new sfValidatorFile(array(
    'mime_types' => $mime_types
), array(
    'invalid'    => 'Invalid file.',
    'required'   => 'Select a file to upload.',
    'mime_types' => 'The file type is incorrect.'
));
```

**Edit:**

All right, I see what you want. You're code is almost right but regarding how the `mime_types` check is done, if you give an array, it means it's an array of mime_types, not an array of categories. If you don't give an array, it means it's a mime category.

This sounds like a bug in symfony, but then you should give a merge array and then pass it to the mime_types option.

Comment: This is not the solution I was looking for. I had already mention I donot want to merge categories/types into single array. I just wanted to know why this was not working.

Comment: + web_images mime-category is already there in the validator by default, I should have been able to simply add array for application/pdf as a category and then add it to the mime_type along with web_images, like: 'mime_types' => array('application', 'web_images') without redifining category list for web_images